# How to input a slider in this form?

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I want to add a slider in the form tag. Right now all the pictures are together. i want to make it more user friendly. As you can see in my code i'm fetching all images from database. And i've override the input radio button on each image so that the user can select its image.

I've already tried to use the Slick library but its not good.

```
<style type="text/css">
/*
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
*/

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 100px auto;
    }

    .slick-slide {
      margin: 0px 20px;
    }

    .slick-slide img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
      color: black;
    }


    .slick-slide {
      transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
      opacity: .2;
    }

    .slick-active {
      opacity: .5;
    }

    .slick-current {
      opacity: 1;
    }
      .img{
          width: 10%;
      }
  </style>

<style media="screen">
.input-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label>img {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #090;
}


input[type=radio]:checked + label>img {
  transform: 
    rotateZ(-10deg) 
    rotateX(10deg);
}

/* Stuff after this is only to make things more pretty */
input[type=radio] + label>img {

  width: 115px;
  height: 115px;
  transition: 500ms all;
}
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="preview.php" method="post" >
     <?php

    $result_model = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM model ORDER BY id DESC ");
    $result_metal = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM metal ORDER BY id DESC ");
    $result_stone = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM stone ORDER BY id DESC "); ?>


    <div >
    <div class="input-group">
      <p>Choose your Model:</p>
    </div>
     <div class="regular slider">
    <?php
    while($model = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_model)){

    ?>
<!--    <input type="radio" name="model" id="model<?= $model['id'] ?>" class="input-hidden" value="<?= $model['id'] ?>" />-->
<!--

    <label for="model<?= $model['id'] ?>">
-->
      <img 
        src="images/<?= $model['image'] ?>"
        alt="<?= $model['name'] ?>" style="width:50%;" />

<!--    </label>-->

    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <?php
        }   
    ?>
<!--    </div>-->
<!--      <br>-->
<div>
<!--
    <div class="input-group">
      <p>Choose your Metal:</p>
    </div>
-->
<!--

-->

      </div>
         <br>
       </div>

            <div class="input-group">
      <p>Choose your Metal:</p>
    </div>
        <div class="regular slider">
   <?php
    while($metal = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_metal)){

    ?>
<!--
    <input type="radio" name="metal" id="metal<?= $metal['id'] ?>" class="input-hidden"  value="<?= $metal['id'] ?>" />

-->
<!--    <label for="metal<?= $metal['id'] ?>">-->
      <img 
        src="images/<?= $metal['image'] ?>"
        alt="<?= $metal['name'] ?>" />
<!--    </label>-->
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <?php
        }   
    ?>
    ?>
<!--    </div>-->
<!--      <br>-->
<div>
<!--
    <div class="input-group">
      <p>Choose your Metal:</p>
    </div>
-->
<!--

-->

      </div>
       </div>



 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
       $(".regular").slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      });
      });
</script>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: To avoid confusion, refer to your desired element as a carousel.  A "slider" can mean something else in the context of a form.

Comment: @mickmackusa I just need a scroll to scroll the pictures side to side

Comment: @DLBum try looking up Owl Carousel